# Pulling yourself upward with a pulley — How is this consistent with energy conservation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, work, free-body-diagram

Suppose you are in a cage suspended by a massless rope that goes around an ideal frictionless pulley. You are supposed to pull yourself up using the rope. You and your cage together are of mass $m$. Let's say you are pulling yourself up at a constant velocity, so the acceleration is zero. We can solve for the force $T$ you have to apply to the rope.

[image]

You apply a force $T$ on the rope downward, which puts a tension on the rope. Your cage is pulled up by the rope with a force $T$ upward. By Newton's third law, there is an additional force $T$ upward. The gravitational force on the cage is $mg$ downward. Assuming you are pulled at constant velocity, we must have
$$ 2T - mg = 0, $$
so then
$$ T = \frac{mg}{2}. $$
Now if there is a mistake here, please correct me, because this solution is crucial to my question. This seems consistent with hint and solutions found on other parts of the internet.

### Question

My question is, how is this consistent with conservation of energy? Let's say you pull yourself up to a height $h$ from the ground. The amount of work you've done is $W = \int_{[0, h]} F\, dx = mgh/2$, which is how much energy you've put in to lift yourself, but you've gained gravitational potential energy $\Delta U = mgh$. It seems you've gained more energy than you've put in. How do you resolve this apparent paradox?

I realize that in order for the person to go up by $h$, they would have to pull $2h$ worth of rope. Presumably, we would want to plug in $2h$ into the work formula and we would get the "correct answer" here. What I'm wondering exactly is, how can we justify plugging in $2h$ instead of $h$ into the work formula? Moreover, what exactly is wrong with my reasoning to begin with? Plugging in $2h$ just because they had to pull $2h$ worth of rope seems ad-hoc, so I am wondering if there is a way to justify it from first principles.

Comment: In order for yourself to be lifted by distance $h$, you must pull $2h$ worth of rope through your hands.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, that is true. I updated my post incorporating that fact. This leads me to ask, how does this dispute my naive approach? And what would be the right way to get to the correct answer and what would be the justification?

Comment: Your increased potential energy at the end comes from the chemical energy burned by your muscles that did the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how is this consistent with conservation of energy?

The easiest and clearest way to analyze such problems is not using the work formula but using the power formula: $$P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$$

Now, if $\hat x$ is the upwards pointing unit vector then at the hand $$P=\vec F \cdot \vec v=(T\hat x)\cdot(-v\hat x)=-vT$$ and at the cage $$P=\vec F \cdot \vec v=(T\hat x)\cdot(v\hat x)=vT$$

So the total power from the rope is $vT-vT=0$ which is as it must be since the rope gets all of its energy from you.

The power from gravity is $$P=\vec F \cdot \vec v= (-mg\hat x) \cdot (v \hat x)=-mgv$$ so mechanical energy is leaving you at a rate of $mgv$ and being converted to gravitational potential energy.

In order to be consistent with the conservation of energy there must be some form of internal energy which is decreasing at the rate of $mgv$. This was not specified in the problem, but it is consistent with experience and required for the conservation of energy.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. When we talk about power, we are talking about a rate of energy transfer. The rate of energy transfer from your hands to the rope is $P = (-T\hat{x})\cdot (-v\hat{x}) = Tv$. The rate of energy transfer from the rope onto the cage is $P = (T\hat{x})\cdot (v\hat{x}) = Tv$. The rope overall has a rate change in energy of $P_{\text{total}} = +Tv - Tv = 0$. [...]

Comment: [...] Now what about the cage itself? The rate of energy transfer from the rope onto the cage is $P = (T\hat{x})\cdot (v\hat{x}) = Tv$. But _there is an additional energy transfer from your hands onto the cage itself_ when you are pulling the rope downward: $P = (T\hat{x})\cdot (v\hat{x})$. (This is similar to how if you're in space, and if you push yourself off a box your chemical energy is transferred to both the KE of the box AND you.) Thus, the total power given to the cage+person system is $P = P_{\text{rope}}+P_{\text{hands}} = 2Tv = mgv$, which matches $-mgv$ from gravity. [...]

Comment: [...] This isn't quite what you said in your post (although maybe I just didn't understand what you wrote), so correct me if I'm wrong or misled. Nonetheless, this post helped me a lot. I might post my own answer to explain it in my (maybe idiosyncratic) terms.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal sounds good. One or two small details may help. Sometimes it is helpful to specifically talk about $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$ as “mechanical power”. In this problem there is also some unspecified source of electrical or chemical power that follows different rules (e.g. $P=IV$). Since the hands are not exerting a force on the cage, I would not say there is any mechanical power going between hands and cage. The force with the cage is at the person’s butt. So the mechanical power transfer between the cage and the person is at their butt, not their hands

Answer (score 3):

How you approach this depends if you are asking for the work done on the rope versus the work done on the cage. In computing $W=\int F dx$, one must integrate over the distance travelled by whatever is feeling the force. If you are using the force felt by the rope (i.e., $T$), then you must use the distance travelled by the rope (i.e., $2h$). If you are using the force felt by the cage, you have to use a force $mg$ to counter the constant force of gravity and the cage travels a distance $h$, so everything works out.

Answer (score 0):

the equation of motion is

$$M\ddot z=T-M\,g$$

from here

$$\frac m2 \dot z^2=\int_0^h (T-M\,g)\,dz$$

thus : If $~T~$ is constant you obtain
the energy
$$E=\frac m2 \dot z^2+(M\,g-T)\,h=\text{constant}$$

the energy is also conserved  if $~T=T(z) ~$ but not if $~T=T(t)~$  (for example $~T=A\,\sin(\omega\,t)~$